# Can I use the mit-ros-pkg in ROS Electric?

Tags: ros, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use the mit-ros-pkg in ROS Electric? I do not see any instructions for software setup for the ROS Electric version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29536/can-i-use-the-mit-ros-pkg-in-ros-electric?/) by [kunalbajaj23](https://answers.ros.org/users/1952/kunalbajaj23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can
for example i use hand_interaction in ros electric , this link can help you to use this
[hand_interaction](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/HandDetection)

---

Originally posted by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) with karma: 41 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0